# GUI wallet cosmetic issue

Tags: monero-wallet-gui

My computer is showing completely messy the characters of the GUI interface.

This is start happen when i upgrade to 0.17.2.2.

[image: Text]

I try to reinstall and uninstall doesn't works always not show characters.

This is win10 Pro build 19042.1052

Comment: What language pack does your OS use? Try to switch to the English one

Comment: @Kurogane - Can you try launching via the `start-low-graphics-mode.bat` batch file that is included?